# How to stream a single float variable from client to backend with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, stream

I am capturing data in the browser at about 15 fps that I would like to stream to my server. Right now this is just a single float var (`distance`). I am using socket.io-stream & socket.io to communicate between server and client. Basic io.emit() and io.on() events are working, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to stream a single var--I have even tried converting the single float to a `Blob()`, and `ArrayBuffer`, but I cannot see the data update on the server.

Here is my frontend code:

```
var distance = new Blob([0]) // init distance var to be streamed
var stream = ss.createStream();

ss(socket).emit('distanceStream', stream, {"DistanceStreamData":distance});
ss.createBlobReadStream(distance).pipe(stream);

...

function update(){
  ...
  distance = new Blob([myDynamicallyChangingFloatVar]) 
  ...
}
```

Backend:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  ss(socket).on('distanceStream', function(stream, data) {
    console.log("got the stream!",stream,data)
  });
});
```

My `console.log()` on the server side just prints the full Stream object, and data is just `"DistanceStreamData":{}`.

All the examples online use `fs` and stream file data or binary data, but I just want to stream a single float variable calculated in the browser. Also please let me know if there is a much simpler way to go about doing this (or even if I'm barking up the wrong tree with socket.io-stream. I initially thought of calling io.emit() 15 times a second in the browser but felt that was probably not a great way of going about this lol...)

Comment: Why are you using socket.io-stream at all?  With plain socket.io, you can just directly send a message containing your single variable at any time.  To send a single value (or group of values), just send a message where you variable is the data.  I don't see any reason to use a stream here?  The whole simplicity of socket.io is you send a message with data whenever you want.  That's all it sounds like you need to do.

Comment: would it be robust enough to get near real time performance if I was calling emit() events in the browser at least 15 times a second in an Update loop? (I honestly don't know the answer to this, which is why i decided on stream)

Comment: 15 times/sec will depend upon your infrastructure, both server and client and network between them.  But socket.io stream won't be any better than just sending a simple socket.io message as both are just built on top of webSocket packets.  In fact, socket.io-stream probably has yet another layer.  So start simple with the plain socket.io message and see how well that works for you and it's trivial to send your single float using a plain socket.io message.

Comment: Ah this seems to work adequately, I may have been overthinking the complexity of the problem and not totally understood the socket.io/-stream infrastructure. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you just use a plain socket.io message.  That will make it easy to send your variable.   You can either send it directly as the data or you can wrap it in an object and make it a property of that object and send the object.  Sending as an object makes it a bit more extensible if you want to then send more than one piece of data.

A socket.io-stream is a layer on top of socket.io which is a layer on top of the webSocket transport so the stream won't be more efficient than a plain socket.io message and the stream may actually incur additional overhead (be less efficient).  In addition, the stream does not offer a built-in mechanism for sending structured data.  Like any stream, you have to add a data format to the stream for you to be able to interpret data sent in a stream.  Whereas the plain socket.io message already does that for you.

So, I'd suggest you start simple with a plain socket.io message.